# Defining entry points tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I'm building a practice newsreader app.
And want to show articles in a tableview.

The articles can be favorited.
And in the tabbar i want to have a extra tab for only my favorited articles. 
I don't want to make another table view because all i have to do is get a differt api call.

Is it possible to check which relationship root -> tableview is used to enter the view?

[view setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNNLR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `View Hierarchy` that you provided and the given requirement, it seems that you want to know the `index` of the `UITabBarController` in which your `UITableViewController` is opened.

You can get this using `tabBarController` property of your `UITableViewController` and the using `selectedIndex` on it, i.e.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)
    }
}
```

Let me know if I don't understand your exact requirement or you face any other issue with this.